# How do you hide an operator when importing?

Tags: haskell

Here's my code, trying to redefine `*`. It could be achieved only when `*` previously hided:

```
import Prelude hiding (*)

(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int
x * 0 = 0
x * y = x + x*(y-1)
```

But it doesn't work:

```
$ ghci test.hs
```

> GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
>
> test.hs:1:24: error: parse error on input ‘*’
>
> Failed, modules loaded: none.
>
> Prelude>

I could hide other function as:

```
import Prelude hiding (read)

import Prelude hiding (show)
```

while it doesn't work for operator like `*`, `+`, `-`.

How do I hide them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Recall how you query `ghci` for type of a function:

```
:t read
:t show
```

About operator:

Do you type `:t +`?

No, you would receive a parse error then.

You do `:t (+)`.

As for your case, you hide it with additional brackets: `((*))`

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))

(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int
x * 0 = 0
x * y = x + x*(y-1)
```